# VS2010 Intellisense behavior change (not fixed by ctrl-alt-space)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My intellisense is running like normal, except that it doesn't show me the parameters of a function or any overloads.

If I type in

```
HttpWebRequest req = new HttpWebRequest(
```

I don't get to see anything about the constructor of HttpWebRequest.  It's very annoying.  This just happened in the last few days (I think) after I updated the Productivity Power Tools (again, I think).

I've tried playing with the options in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor  All Languages and C#, and Auto list members is checked, and so is Parameter information.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've tried disabling the Productivity Power tools...

Comment: Disabling and Re-enabling worked.  Sorry for wasting time.  Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4 the HttpWebRequest constructor is protected and marked as obsolete. That means you can only call the constructor from a derived class. If you complete the statement manually it should give a "inaccessible due to its protection level" compiler error.

Comment: And that makes sense, too.  But it did happen on other things as well, I just put out a bad example.