# Visual Studio's Intellisense Broken With Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, productivity-power-tools

In Visual Studio 2010, the general format of Intellisense/Tooltips is radically altered after installing the Productivity Power Tools.  In my opinion, the change severely harms productivity.  The below images show the before and after:

**With Productivity Power Tools Uninstalled/Disabled:**
[image]

**With Productivity Power Tools Installed/Enabled:**
[image]

What is the option that I need to disable within Productivity Power Tools to turn this off?  I like some of the tools but definitely dislike this particular one.  I've tried toggling all of the obvious ones but can't seem to find the correct one.

Note:  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437680/vs2010-intellisense-behavior-change-not-fixed-by-ctrl-alt-space) question is asking about a similar issue but the accepted answer seems totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

The option you are looking for is called **Solution Navigator**.

You can get to this option by clicking the "Tools" menu in Visual Studio and selecting "Options...".  Scroll down the left pane until you see "Productivity Power Tools".  Select it.  You will see a bunch of On/Off switches.  Scroll down the right pane until you see "Solution Navigator".  Turn it off and restart Visual Studio.  It took me forever to identify the culprit and I hope this answer will save others some precious time.

[image]

Solution Navigator seems like it wouldn't be the culprit but the [documentation](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) states:

> Solution Navigator also provides interactive tooltips in C# and VB
>   code (replacing the default “quick info” tooltips) that give you the
>   same kind of data, but right at your fingertips.

It's a shame that you can't disable just the tooltips, it's all or nothing.  The solution navigator itself is actually kind of nifty.

Comment: It used to be seperate, in the previous versions :(

Answer (score 5):

If you go into the settings for the Productivity Power Tools (Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools) there is a node called Solution Navigator.  In that node there is an "Enable interactive tooltips" option. Make sure that is unchecked to disable the Power Tools tool tips and get the normal Visual Studio tool tips back.

colithium's answer is what led me to find this setting. I'm using version 10.0.20626.18, I'm not sure if that is the case in earlier versions.

[image: Visual Studio Power Tools Settings Pane]